# Is apply and unapply a constructor in scala

Tags: scala

In Java we can make a constructor using the class name.
But in scala I have seen different uses of apply and unapply. Is this the same like the usage of a constructor in Java, in which we can use apply and unapply as a constructor?

Comment: `.apply` is function application, can be used as factory (not constructor) but far from being limited to only that. `.apply` is extractor, for pattern matching. Have a look at related tutorials.

Comment: unapply is the extractor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apply()` *can* be used as factory method (not a constructor), and it often is, but it is not restricted or required to be so. What makes `apply()` special is just that it can be "silently" invoked.

```
class MyClass(arg: String) {
  def apply(n: Int):String = arg*n
}

val mc = new MyClass("blah")
mc.apply(2)  // res0: String = blahblah
mc(3)        // res1: String = blahblahblah
```

You'll often see `apply()` used as a factory method in a companion object.

```
object MyClass {
  def apply(s: String): MyClass = new MyClass(s)
}
val mc = MyClass("bliss")  // call the object's apply() method
```

But, again, that's just a convenient convention, not a requirement.

`unapply()` (and `unapplySeq()`) is different in that it is "silently" called whenever you attempt to pattern match on a class instance.

```
class MyClass(val arg: String) {}
object MyClass {
  def unapply(x: MyClass): Option[String] = Some(x.arg)
}
val mc = new MyClass("bland")
mc match {
  case MyClass(s) => println(s"got $s")  // output: "got bland"
  case _          => println("not")
}
```

Comment: is this a requirement for `unapply` method signature that it should return `Option[T]` instead of `T`?

Comment: I've found out explanation on signature in the end of this article: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html.
Found your short explanation of `unapply` very useful. If I understand things correct then whenever I design a class which I want to be able to pattern match - I need to provide `unapply` implementation in the companion object, right?

Comment: @AlexanderArendar; You can always pattern match on the type of a variable. So `case x:MyClass => ...` will work. You need the `unapply()` method to "extract" information/data from a class instance. So `case MyClass(x) => ...` won't compile without the `unapply()` method defined.

Answer (score 2):

> in java we can make a constructor using class name.
>   but in scala I have seen different use of apply and unapply, is this the same like constructor in java, in which we can use apply and unapply as a constructor

No.

In Scala, the constructor is invoked using the `new` operator (just like in Java) and is named `this` (the primary constructor doesn't have a name at all, it is just the body of the class).

`apply` and `unapply` aren't constructors, they are *methods*. Methods are different from constructors in Scala (just like they are in Java). The only thing special about `apply` is that `foo()` gets interpreted as `foo.apply()` *if* there is no method named `foo` in scope. In other words, `apply` allows you to make your own function-like objects.

`unapply` is called when you try to "break apart" an object using *Pattern Matching*. It allows an object to decide which part of itself it will expose to pattern matching and how. In other words: it is required to preserve object-oriented data abstraction in the face of pattern matching.

Since the purpose of `unapply` is to extract values from an object, it is in some sense the exact *opposite* of a constructor, whose purpose it is to collect values and *hide* them in an object.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. `Apply` can call constructor but it's not the equal things, it came from functional programming paradigm. From Wikipedia: function application is the act of applying a function to an argument from its domain so as to obtain the corresponding value from its range. So, `apply` it's just applying the function to argument, and yes in Scala monads classes, inside apply they usually call constructors. But in other functions apply can do different things. 
`Unapply` it's construction for pattern matching, but semantically it's vice versa operation to `apply`. It says: give me object which was create by applying function to argument X, and I will return you this argument X.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the difference is mostly in style. I prefer the usage of apply as it is more functional from the companion object perspective. But as Scala does not define destructor methods (like you do in C++) in the class , it becomes more natural to use apply as you might need to define the unapply method and would have a clear design explicitly defining both at the same level.