# Scala: which classes should not have companion objects?

Tags: scala, companion-object

The following pattern seems to be idiomatic scala:

```
class Foo() {}
object Foo { def apply() = new Foo() }
val x = Foo()
```

What is the motivation for the idiomatic approach?  In which cases should I *not* provide the factory method, forcing client to use `val y = new Foo()`?  Should all cases with companion objects provide a factory method?

Comment: This is, amongst other things, what `case` classes are for. `case class Foo() {}` will generate automatically the `object Foo` with the same `apply` method (in fact it will generate even more than that).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751212/is-apply-and-unapply-a-constructor-in-scala/45752243#45752243) to a previous question addresses most of your questions.

Comment: Two [additional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609744/what-is-the-rationale-behind-having-companion-objects-in-scala) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806029/scala-companion-object-purpose) of almost same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class does not need a companion object if none of the following apply:

- There is functionality in the class that is not tied to an instance (what is called "static" in Java)
- There is a desire to provide a constructor that avoids the need to call `new`. This is accomplished in Scala by having `SomeClass.apply(params)`

If none of the above are of interest, there is no need for the companion object.
A companion object is a useful structure - if you have those needs. If not, there is no reason to have it. I am not aware of any reason to **categorically not** have a companion object. It's a tool that you don't write if you don't need to.

Comment: I think the question might be rephrased to "*For which classes do we desire a constructor without the need for `new`*"? Is there a convention?

Comment: @Bergi -- Indeed, this is what I am getting at.  I also saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/630015/6296589).  I understand that in many cases it is not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

Case class apply is normally rewritten by the compiler to new. That's not done if you write a custom apply, even a trivial one.

There are probably similar edge cases around implicit value classes.

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> case class K(i: Int)
defined class K

scala> K(42)
res0: K = K(42)

scala> :javap -c res0
Compiled from "<console>"
public class $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$ {
  public static $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class $line4/$read$$iw$$iw$
       3: invokespecial #28                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$K res0();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #31                 // Field res0:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$K;
       4: areturn

  public $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #33                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: putstatic     #35                 // Field MODULE$:L$line4/$read$$iw$$iw$;
       8: aload_0
       9: new           #14                 // class $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$K
      12: dup
      13: bipush        42
      15: invokespecial #38                 // Method $line3/$read$$iw$$iw$K."<init>":(I)V
      18: putfield      #31                 // Field res0:L$line3/$read$$iw$$iw$K;
      21: return
}

scala> case class K(i: Int) ; object K { def apply(j: Int) = new K(j) }
defined class K
defined object K

scala> K(42)
res1: K = K(42)

scala> :javap -c res1
Compiled from "<console>"
public class $line6.$read$$iw$$iw$ {
  public static $line6.$read$$iw$$iw$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class $line6/$read$$iw$$iw$
       3: invokespecial #31                 // Method "<init>":()V
       6: return

  public $line5.$read$$iw$$iw$K res1();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #34                 // Field res1:L$line5/$read$$iw$$iw$K;
       4: areturn

  public $line6.$read$$iw$$iw$();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #36                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: putstatic     #38                 // Field MODULE$:L$line6/$read$$iw$$iw$;
       8: aload_0
       9: getstatic     #41                 // Field $line5/$read$$iw$$iw$K$.MODULE$:L$line5/$read$$iw$$iw$K$;
      12: bipush        42
      14: invokevirtual #45                 // Method $line5/$read$$iw$$iw$K$.apply:(I)L$line5/$read$$iw$$iw$K;
      17: putfield      #34                 // Field res1:L$line5/$read$$iw$$iw$K;
      20: return
}
```